# How can I get the return type of a Lambda expression

Tags: java, generics, lambda, types

Is there there any way to get the return type of a lambda expression in Java?

When it is an Anonymous class it is working like this.

```
Supplier<String> supplier = new Supplier<String>() {
    @Override
    public String get() {
        return "asd";
    }
};
((ParameterizedTypeImpl) supplier.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0]
```

But this is not working.

```
Supplier<String> supplier2 = () -> "asd";
((ParameterizedTypeImpl) supplier.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0]
```

Comment: A lambda _body_ can match more than one type of functional interface, so from that directly there's not much to be retrieved. When you assign it to an interface (e.g. `Supplier`), _then_ you can get the parameterized types from `Class#getTypeParameters`. Your first example actually implements the `Supplier` interface as an anonymous subclass, whereas the second example is a lambda which was assigned to `Supplier`. I _assume_ that means (per the javadoc) that there are no interfaces it extends from, so you get an empty array back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe abstract classes such as `Supplier` can be instantiated

Not sure what your end goal is, but could you possibly try to cast the lambda expression to `Supplier`?

Would look like this:

```
Supplier<String> supplier2 = (Supplier)() -> "asd";
((ParameterizedTypeImpl) supplier.getClass().getGenericInterfaces([0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```